# Looking for datasheet for Alpha 21264C

Tags: datasheet, cpu

Not too long back I did some reading on the Alpha CPU architecture and (probably out of a burst of nostalgic stupidity) procured a couple; there's only an issue - the ones I have are the 21264 `C` variant, that features an LGA pad-out rather than a PGA setup due to the increased clock speed.

The initial Alpha 21264 datasheet I've tracked down, but I can't seem to find any references anywhere as to the 21264C variant's datasheets, which would contain the prerequisite pinouts and mechanical specs for me to do anything with these devices. Because Compaq offed the whole Alpha architecture, there doesn't appear to be a reliable manufacturer source anywhere on these devices.

Not that I have any game-changing ideas for these things, but it'd be kinda neat to do something with them other than have them gather dust or buy a complete OEM system for them. Or, if nothing else, learn about them for learning's sake.

Anyone have any clues as to where I could find the particular datasheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_21264#Alpha_21264C) points to EV68DC being an a.k.a. of the C variant. This led me to the [21264/EV68DC Microprocessor Hardware Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/dec-21264ev68cb_ev68dc_hrm).